# CAPS Pagemenu : willMoveToPage delegate method getting error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I am using **UIPageMenuController**. While clicking the button I have to go to 3 page. 
I am trying to call will **willMoveToPage** delegate method, getting error

**willMoveToPage:index:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Below my code :

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let yourVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileConnectionsController") as! ProfileConnectionsController
        pageMenu?.delegate?.willMoveToPage!(yourVC, index: 2)
```

Comment: pageMenu are you conform the delegate in your current class as `self`

Comment: ji pannitten. and also coming the same

pageMenu?.delegate = self

Comment: but clear says `willMoveToPage:index` delegate not called

Comment: are you implement this method `func willMoveToPage(controller: UIViewController, index: Int) {`

Comment: willMoveToPage:index:]: will not move to new page. This delegate method will be called when user click any tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error says **willMoveToPage:index:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance** you are not implemented the delegate method

**step-1**

ensure once are you implement the delegate in your class

```
class ViewController:UIViewController,CAPSPageMenuDelegate
```

and ensure once you are confirm the delegate

```
pageMenu.delegate=self
```

**step-2**

> After that you will be able to set up the following delegate methods inside of your parent view controller

ensure once are you called the method

```
func willMoveToPage(controller: UIViewController, index: Int) {
   if let getSubview=controller as! ProfileConnectionsController
   {
    getSubview.pageNumber=index
  }
}
```